# SQL query for data filtering

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 6 input fields

```
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-width namef" placeholder="Product Name">
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-width brandf" placeholder="Brand Name">
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-width catf" placeholder="Category">
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-width sizef" placeholder="Size">
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-width pricef" placeholder="Price">
<input type="text" class="form-control filter-width invf" placeholder="Inventory">
```

each field is used to filter data. if all fields are filled then it is easy to querying data but I actually don't know using how many fields a user is going to filter. He may filter the data using only name, name and brand name, name and brand name and size, price and inventory. putting conditions using `if, elseif` and thinking of all possible combinations would be difficult and lengthy task. 
is there any way to achieve this.
Here's my PHP:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $brand = $_REQUEST['brand'];
        $cat = $_REQUEST['cat'];
        $size = $_REQUEST['size'];
        $price = $_REQUEST['price'];
        $inv = $_REQUEST['inv'];
        if(!empty($name) AND !empty($brand) AND !empty($cat) AND !empty($size) AND !empty($price) AND !empty($inv) ||){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pname='$name' AND brand_name ='$brand' AND ptype = '$cat' AND psize= '$size' AND sprice = '$price' AND inventory='$inv'";
        }
        else{

        }
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                $pid = $row['pid'];
                $pname = $row['pname'];
                $pbrand = $row['brand_name'];
                $pcat = $row['ptype'];
                $pinv = $row['inventory'];
                $pprice = $row['sprice'];
                $psize = $row['psize']; ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $pid; ?>" class="prod-details"><?php echo "<td>".$pid."</td><td>".$pname."</td><td>".$pbrand."</td>"."<td>".$pcat."</td>"."<td>".$psize."</td>"."<td>".$pprice."</td>"."<td>".$pinv."</td>"; ?></tr> <?php
            }
        }
```

Now I don't know what conditions to think and write inside `else` body

Comment: post your sql query  ..

Comment: I just wrote a simple sql query which will only work if all inputs are filled. `SELECT * FROM products WHERE pname='$name' AND brand_name ='$brand' AND ptype = '$cat' AND psize= '$size' AND sprice = '$price' AND inventory='$inv'`

Comment: add your PHP as well, and update your original post with both php and sql

Comment: edited the question with PHP

Comment: I think just get all the values in the inputs, then if inputs are empty then SQL will automatically compare the brand name, for example  to the empty string, which wont return anything

Comment: okay let me try this

Comment: AND consider using PDO Prepared Statements to avoid SQL injection! https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PDO+prepared+statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 AND ";

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    $columnName = '';
    switch ($key) {
        case 'name':
            $columnName = 'pname';
            break;

        case 'brand':
            $columnName = 'brand_name';
            break;

        case 'cat':
            $columnName = 'ptype';
            break;

        case 'cat':
            $columnName = 'psize';
            break;

        case 'size':
            $columnName = 'ptype';
            break;

        case 'inv':
            $columnName = 'inventory';
            break;
    }

    if (!empty($columnName) && !empty($value)) {
        $sql .= " $columnName='$value' AND";
    }
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, 'AND');

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $pid = $row['pid'];
        $pname = $row['pname'];
        $pbrand = $row['brand_name'];
        $pcat = $row['ptype'];
        $pinv = $row['inventory'];
        $pprice = $row['sprice'];
        $psize = $row['psize']; ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $pid; ?>" class="prod-details"><?php echo "<td>".$pid."</td><td>".$pname."</td><td>".$pbrand."</td>"."<td>".$pcat."</td>"."<td>".$psize."</td>"."<td>".$pprice."</td>"."<td>".$pinv."</td>"; ?></tr> <?php
    }
}
```

Also please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could **aggregate** your query string. You may try the following-

```
$query = "";
    if (!empty($name)) {
            $query += " AND pname='$name'";
    }
    if (!empty($brand)) {
            $query += " AND brand_name ='$brand'";
    }
    if (!empty($cat)) {
            $query += " AND ptype = '$cat'";
    }
    if (!empty($size)) {
            $query += " AND psize= '$size'";
    }
    if (!empty($price)) {
            $query += " AND sprice = '$price'";
    }
    if (!empty($inv)) {
            $query += " AND inventory='$inv'";
    }

    if($query != ""){
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1" . $query;
    }else{
      }
```

Comment: use magic `1` to make the `where` part valid in case no filter is selected, ie. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1 " . $query;`  AND you are missing a space just after the `where`

Comment: No, there is no specification here what will happen if no data or query is selected and for second part, i have used space at the time of joining query string.

Comment: actually youo do not need the `if (sizeof($query) < 1).. else`  part if you use the `1` after `WHERE` and then you can start each $query += " AND ..." with the `AND`